# Docker doesn't see changes in project files

Tags: docker

Docker starts up and the project works,
but if I change any file in the project via IDE, after refreshing the page in the browser, these changes are not visible.
the docker container does not see them, only after restarting apache will it update on the docker (not always).
As if he were holding a cache and just downloading it.

Problems began to occur after the last docker desktop update.

Please direct me to solve the problem.

EDIT:

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
   web:
       image: project
       build: ./docker/web/
       container_name: project
       restart: unless-stopped
  links:
       - redis
       - db
  ports:
       - 8080:80
       - 443:443
  volumes:
        - './:/var/www/app'
        - './docker/web/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled'
  depends_on:
        - redis
        - db
  environment:
       CONTAINER_ROLE: app
       APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
       TZ: "Europe/Warsaw"
```

Comment: What kind of app is that? How is supposed Docker to see changes in files? Be clearer.

Comment: My OS is Windows 10, I`m using Docker desktop.
I just make changes to the files, save them and you can't see the changes on the docker.
The changes are visible only after running the docker-compose --build up command.
In editing the post I put the code of my docker-compose

Comment: docker is to make a separate container, how you can expect that you will make changes in your IDE and changes will be done in the docker container. Have some clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue being worked on with the 2.2.0.0 release.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5530

The filesystem sharing was completely rewritten in this release and there appear to be some bugs reported once it hit GA.

Comment: downgrade to version 2.1.0.5 helped, from your link

Comment: I still encounter this problem on version 2.5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to change the workdir path to match the volume path

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    web:
        volumes: 
            - .:/usr/src/my_app
```

Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/my_app
```